# using an if statement to compare two strings in shell

Tags: bash, shell

This might be a stupid question, but i have never had to anything like this in scripting. So any help would be appreciated.

I am dealing with data from a census and have to generate reports.
Each line in the file has a last name, frequency, etc etc.  I have to grab the frequency.
But if i grab some ones last name who has a frequency of "0.000" then i have to change it to "0.00025".  I attempted to do an if statement but am not sure how to do it.

```
#!/bin/bash
all=/homes/ddailey/public_html/data/dist_all_last

count=`grep -w $1 $all | awk '{ print $2 }'`

if [ $count == "0.000" ]; then
   echo .00025
else
   echo $count
fi
```

Comment: This isn't perfect, but it looks like it should do what you describe. What's the problem with it?

Comment: Yeah i know its not perfect, just put it together in a few minutes.  The problem is that if $count greps a string that is 0.000 it doesnt change it to .00025.  It just keeps it at 0.000

Comment: As written it shouldn't change `count`'s value, but it should *echo* .00025. Does it do that?

Comment: How many lines are in the file?  If there's more than one, that's the trouble.  See also [How to debug a shell script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/951336/).

Comment: it doesnt echo .00025, it echo's .000... but their is more than one line in the file

Answer (score 1):

The first statement

```
count=`grep -w $1 $all | awk '{ print $2 }'`
```

is returning a *list* of values separated by newlines. A simple `echo` won't show the newlines but this will:

```
echo "$count"
```

The `if` statement, however, expects a single value, so if you have two or more results in `$count` it will not match the single test value. What you need to do is loop through the values in `$count`. Try the following:

```
counts=`grep -w $1 $all | awk '{ print $2 }'`
for count in $counts
do
    if [ $count == "0.000" ]; then
       echo .00025
    else
       echo $count 
    fi
done
```

I prefer the following design which puts all your logic into the awk command. That keeps all your processing logic in one script, not split across awk and bash.

```
grep -w $1 $all |
awk '{ if ($2 == "0.000") $2 = "0.00025"; print $2 }'
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Pick a shell.  The Bourne Again Shell (bash) and the basic /bin/sh are both popular.  There are a number of other options which you should not use.
2. Specific advice.  Google.  Really.  See [Compare a string in Unix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10849297/compare-a-string-in-unix) for your answer, or [How do I compare strings in Bourne Shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183622/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-bourne-shell) if using bash.
3. Watch spaces.  Shell programming is sensitive to white space, so having or forgetting a space breaks scripts.  For example, make sure you remember the space before and after '[' or ']'.   Getting it to run often involves adding and removing spaces.
4. Watch for empty replacements.   `if [ $nosuchvar = 3 ]` makes an error but `if [ "$nosuchvar" = 3 ]` does not.   Also, glob replacements, so `if [[ $foo == "a*" ]]` is different than `if [ $foo == "a*" ]`
5. Dump the shell.  Running Python or another 'real' language is usually far cleaner and more maintainable than any shell script over five lines.